# Difference between schemas in GraphQL and Relay

Tags: javascript, relay, graphql

The schemas of GraphQL and Relay differ a bit, like Relay has connections for example. Is it still possible to do queries to these nodes with cURL, for instance, on a Relay schema with connections? Or what is the best way to check if the schema is working accordingly?

Comment: Hi. I updated your title to reflect the first question you asked. Feel free to reset it, but try using a very *specific* title to  better draw peoples attention. Also, consider adding a minimal code example, and elaborate on the particular part of that example code that you are wondering about. For guidance, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Certainly, thanks i was on the phone, just had to ask before I forgot :)

Answer (score 0):

> The schemas of GraphQL and Relay differ a bit

This isn't really a valid statement. GraphQL server defines a GraphQL schema, and Relay (a GraphQL client) uses that schema. It doesn't have any special version of it.

The Nodes, Connections and Object Mutations are Relay-specific *extensions* to the GraphQL schema. It means that if you want to use Relay, your schema needs to implement the GraphQL-Relay spec in addition to the raw GraphQL spec. You can read more about them [in the docs](http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html), or see the specs for the [GraphQL Schema](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/) and the [Nodes](http://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm), [Connections](http://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) and [Object Mutations](http://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/mutations.htm) extensions.

As for the second part of the question, you can interact with Relay-compliant GraphQL server the same way as with a pure GraphQL server.